# Merge the "objective-c-2" and "objective-c-2.0" tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

There are 213 questions tagged [objective-c-2.0](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2.0), and 1 question tagged [objective-c-2](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2). I removed the tag from other 5 questions, but when I created this very question, the tag was used from 11 questions.

The tags should be merged, and [objective-c-2](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2) made a synonym for the other tag.

[objective-c-2](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2) is already [suggested as synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/objective-c-2.0/synonyms); it just needs to be voted.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Couldn't you simple retag the one and only question tagged with objective-c-2?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm not getting my point across. _Why do you need a synonym?_ Why not just get rid of the tag?